# Getting error when pushing github repsoitory

Tags: github-pages

I get this error when pushing a brand new repo, here is the error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have done research but most are out-dated, I have deleted the folder as well but still gives me this error

Comment: Are you using NPM package `gh-pages` ?

Comment: I want to uses github pages but I haven't put it on yet @SidharthRanasingh

Answer (score 0):

1st remove the remote origin:

`git remote remove origin`

Then add a new remote in this format:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo-name.git`

Comment: I get this :
sage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=(push|fetch)]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from